# I want to pass two parameters in onclick, one is a function & another is a div id

Tags: javascript

I want to sen two id's when onclick occurs like now when div 2 is clicked I want to pass just the id of the 2nd div too & then write script for the 2nd div.
is it possible?  if so, then how? any example?

```
<div id="1st_div"></div>
<div id="2nd_div">
     <div id="inner_of_2nd_div" onclick="myfunction('1st_div')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually I din't get it

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want.

Comment: If you can, try and elaborate what you want, also include any attempts you've made to solve this issue yourself. (Edit your question and include the code there.)

Comment: he's assuming a function in js can only accept one parameter

Comment: send 2 ids to WHAT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as many parameters as you wish.
Just define the function accordingly.

For instance, for a 2 parameters function myFunction, 
your onclick should look like

```
onclick="myfunction(p1, p2)"
```

and your function myFunction like

```
myfunction(p1, p2) {
  //do your stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a function which has id argument of the clicked div. If right, use JQuery and do that:

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"/> 
<div id="1st_div" class="clickable"></div>
                <div id="2nd_div" class="clickable">
                     <div id="inner_of_2nd_div" ></div>
                </div>
```

JS Jquery:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
        var _id=$(this).attr("id");
        alert("I am div id="+_id+" and I've been clicked right now!");
    });
```

Comment: <div id="1st_div"></div>
<div id="2nd_div">
     <div id="inner_of_2nd_div" onclick="myfunction('1st_div'),inner_of_2nd_div"></div>
</div>
i want to call like this
is it possible?
because i've a function which works with the 1st_div id.
now in the same function call 'onclick' i want call the function, & pass just the id of the div where it is called.

Comment: @DebabrataRoy sorry, i dont understand, can you say what you aim, not about code, but about rendering ?

Comment: What I understand: A function works with #1st_div id. Ok. It is in 'onclick'. and you want to pass argument, from onclick, for this function. This argument is the ID of the clicked div. Is this it ? See my new answer please. (editted)

Comment: onclick iwant to call a function "myfunction('div1') and beside the function want to pass the id of the clicked div.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id="1st_div"></div>
<div id="2nd_div">
     <div id="inner_of_2nd_div" onclick="myfunction(document.getElementById('1st_div'));">asa</div>
```

```
<script>
function myfunction(obj)
{
//here i caught the object 
obj.innerHTML=obj.id;
}
</script>
```