# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - sending two values via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send two values via AJAX.

My jQuery function (working fine with single value on the whole page):

```
function randomfunction(qq, xxx)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "https://someurl.php",
       data: "qq="+qq+"&qqq="+xxx,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data)
       {
         jQuery("#stuff"+id).html(data);
       }
     });
 }
```

My input to trigger it:

```
echo"<input class='inputbutton' style='width: 122px!important;' type='button' id='button_id' value='Anfordern' onClick='randomfunction($qq, $xxx);'>";
```

I use this type of setup on my page with single values, which works perfectly.
Now I started using 2 and it always gives me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

I already checked and tried these solutions:

[I want to pass two parameters in onclick, one is a function & another is a div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695970/i-want-to-pass-two-parameters-in-onclick-one-is-a-function-another-is-a-div-i)

[How to send multiple data fields via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/how-to-send-multiple-data-fields-via-ajax/6085669)

```
data: {qq: qq, xxx: xxx},
```

[SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931344/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

[JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558482/javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

and tried a debug with [JSLint](https://jslint.com/) and [JSHint](https://jshint.com/). I also checked my PHP backend and it works perfectly if I access it manually with something like `https://randomlink.php?qq=stuff&xxx=stuff2`.

I even clear my cache everytime I change something to prevent loading old code. I just don't get what is wrong. Can anyone help me? Am I too blind to see the obvious?

Comment: Are you able to console.log the value coming into the function ? like `console.log(qq, xxx)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I couldn't do this. It wouldn't log something. This brought me to the thought, that there is a mistake in my transfer from PHP to JS. I posted an answer which solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently I was searching on the wrong side of the code. The error was not in the function, it was in passing the values from `PHP` to `JS`. If one of the values is a string, like an email address, it needs to be quoted.
I solved it with this addition to my button:

```
echo"<input onClick='randomfunction(\"$qq\", $xxx);'>";
```

Reference:
[How do I pass a PHP string into a Javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905313/how-do-i-pass-a-php-string-into-a-javascript-function-call)